# capture and upload, download and mount disc images (ISO)

Tags: java, php, web, diskimage

I have a intranet PHP application and i would like to give the user the option to:

-> insert a cd/dvd into the drive
-> click the "Copy disk to application button" that will create a disk image (ISO or simular) file and upload it to the application

and when a disk is already uploaded click a

"download and mount" button that will download the image and mount it automatically.

the workstations used are all windows 7

Hope someone can come up with a bright idea how this could be done by a single click.
installing applications on the client pc is not a problem in this case.

Comment: So, what's the actual programming problem you'd like to solve?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create javascript  code on the browser side that can interact with objects lying outside the browser sandboxe. What you are trying to achieve is not possible unless you create an ActiveX control that the user would have to trust and install.